# Imagemagick not working in windows + java

Tags: java, imagemagick

I am using imagemagick in my application. Our development machine is Windows and live server is linux. Now, in online it is working fine online. But not in development machine. I downloaded and installed Imagemagick latest release for Windows and when i try the below command in DOS-prompt, it is working fine.

```
convert -sample 100x100 D:\test.jpg D:\test-cropped.jpg
```

But when i run the same as command-line in Java program, it is not working and not giving any error too.
My code is :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("convert -sample 250x150 "+pathName+digest+".jpg "+pathName+digest+"_thumb.jpg");
```

Any help is appareciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

- execute `convert` using the absolute path
- quote your parameter `input file` and `output file`, in case they contain space

Answer (score 1):

`convert.exe` is available in ImageMagick installation directory. So you need to add ImageMagick installation directory in environment variable `path`.

Another option is to provide complete path of `convert.exe` as :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\program files\\ImageMagick\\convert -sample 250x150 "+pathName+digest+".jpg "+pathName+digest+"_thumb.jpg");
```

Comment: It is already there. *D:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16;*

Comment: try using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"D:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\convert\" -sample 250x150 "+pathName+digest+".jpg "+pathName+digest+"_thumb.jpg");`

Comment: @NandkumarTekale - that is not going to work.  The algorithm that `exec` uses to split the command string doesn't understand quotes or spaces in pathnames.

Comment: This is also working for me. But still i prefer to use single quotes instead of complete path. Thanks for the help Nandkumar.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is spaces in pathnames, but the solution is NOT to use escapes or quotes.  The `exec(String)` method splits the string into "arguments" in a completely naive fashion by looking for white-space. It pays no attention whatsoever to quoting, etcetera.  Instead, you will end up with command names and arguments that have quote characters, etcetera embedded in them.

The solution is to use the overload of `exec` that takes a `String[]`, and do the argument splitting yourself; e.g.

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
         "convert", // or "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\\convert\\"
         "-sample", 
         "250x150", 
         pathName + digest + ".jpg",
         pathName + digest + "_thumb.jpg"
    });
```

The other thing you could do is to capture and print any output that is written to the processes stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem I was facing that from java `compare` command was working fine using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), but when using `convert`, it was not working and returning me exit value as 4.
`Compare` execution returns exit value 0, telling that it is successfully executed.
I have `system path` updated with the ImageMagic's installation directory, still it was not picking 'convert' exe file. So, I started giving complete path of the convert.exe file instead of only writing only `convert`
e.g:
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program files/ImageMagic......../convert.exe myImage1 -draw .... myImage2")` and it worked fine this time.
Some how system was not able to pick the `convert` application and giving full path sorted it out. May be this solution would help someone facing same type of issue.

Comment: Hi Rajneesh and welcome to stack overflow. This may work, but it's quite hard to read (it's a wall of text). could you edit it to be a bit clearer? you can also surround any code in backticks: ` to make it look like code eg `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`